# Where can I get enough cards to play a game of Caravan?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I don't know much about the game, but I know that I need 30 cards to play, and I can't have the same card from the same casino twice in my deck. Where can I get many of them?

I really want to play Caravan...

Comment: read my comment to the answer below about a bug with the cards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can buy a bunch of cards at various merchants, which makes getting a full deck fairly difficult. Alternatively, you can help [Ringo](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Ringo), and he'll give you a full deck.

Note added from Viper_sb's comment:

> If you buy cards at merchants they do not get added to your deck, they stay in your inventory, but you can move them to any container and pick them up again and THEN they are in your deck.

[Source](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout%3A_New_Vegas_bugs#Caravan_bugs)

Comment: Oh, he is in Goodsprings? I have not noticed that when I started the game. :) Thanks for the info :D

Comment: Correct, also a note on the bug would be good. If you buy cards at merchants they do not get added to your deck, they stay in your inventory, but you can move them to any container and pick them up again and THEN they are in your inventory. http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout%3A_New_Vegas_bugs#Caravan_bugs

Comment: @Marius: Yes, he is. He's involved in one of the early game quests.

Comment: The other thing about building a standalone deck is that even if you get 30 cards, they're not likely to be distributed well, so [deck-building strategies](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14290/which-strategy-to-follow-in-building-a-caravan-deck) are out the window.

Answer (score 2):

you can also kill Ringo and grab the deck from his corpse.